# SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider DATABASE_MODE_2LINES configures Recent Suggestions to add a second line of text. Where does that text come from?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-search, android-searchmanager

From [this developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html),

> The database mode must include DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES and can optionally include **DATABASE_MODE_2LINES, which adds another column to the suggestions table** that allows you to provide a second line of text with each suggestion.

From [this reference doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.html#DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES),

> public static final int DATABASE_MODE_2LINES
>
> This mode bit configures the database to include a 2nd annotation line
>   with each entry. *optional*

**The question is that where does this annotation line/text come from?**

*From what I have read* in the developer guide so far, we are not providing any annotation text with our search query which would go in the extra column added in the suggestions table, and later served in Recent Suggestion List as the second annotation line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You* provide it when you save a search query to your collection of recent queries by calling `saveRecentQuery(searchQuery, annotationText)` on an instance of `RecentQuerySuggestions`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent  = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
        suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null); // *** The second argument is that annotation text
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html#SavingQueries)

From the [reference of `saveRecentQuery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/SearchRecentSuggestions.html#saveRecentQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> **public void saveRecentQuery (String queryString, String line2)**
>
> Add a query to the recent queries list. Returns immediately,
>   performing the save in the background.
>
> **Parameters**
>   **queryString**   The string as typed by the user. This string will be displayed as the suggestion, and if the user clicks on the suggestion,
>   this string will be sent to your searchable activity (as a new search
>   query).
>
> **line2** If you have configured your recent suggestions provider with DATABASE_MODE_2LINES, you can pass a second line of text here. It will
>   be shown in a smaller font, below the primary suggestion. When typing,
>   matches in either line of text will be displayed in the list. If you
>   did not configure two-line mode, or if a given suggestion does not
>   have any additional text to display, you can pass null here.